# statistical test for order of movements

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ordinal-data

I have 10 data sets where I have to identify the order of movement of particles. For example, first to move is ranked 1, second to move is 2, and so on.

So for each data set, I have a list of particles and the order of movements. The maximum number of particles is 6. There are cases when particles move at the same time (or when the order is not clear) and were ranked with the same number.

I want to know if there is a statistical test to check if the order of the movement found across data sets might be 'random' or not. I want to find out if the order is 'significant' or not.

Please point me to the correct statistical test for this, and how would you formulate the hypothesis in this case? Your insights will be extremely helpful.

Comment: To be able to assist, I will need a bit more information. In particular, if you could clarify what is meant by "movement found across data sets". It seems to me that this is a situation where you have 6 (¿comparable?) particles in 10 different scenarios, and the recorded data is when each moved when.

Comment: To build on @GreggH 's query, if we identify the 6 particles A-F are A-F the same particle in each dataset? You state 'maximum...6', so I'm guessing not. Are the particles all equivalent? Are they from a fixed number of possible types? If latter is the ratio fixed? You need to define the scenario much more precisely to allow a useful answer.

Comment: The particles are distinguishable. Let us call them A-F, sometimes all A-F particles are present. In other data sets, not all of them are present (perhaps A-E only). So I made a tally of the over they moved: Dataset 1: has the order ADBCEF, dataset 2: BFEDCA, etc.

Comment: But there are rare cases when two particles move together DACB(FE) -- in this case F,E move together. I would like to know if there is a test that would check if this order is random or is due to some factors. And what the null hypothesis would look like.

Comment: ¿If the particles are distinguishable, but all different...then how are they being labeled A thru F (or whatever the last value is)? ¿Aren't the labels arbitrary? If the labels are arbitrary, ¿isn't this a question about randomly assigning a label, "A", "B", ..., to the particle that moved first?